# what would the purpose of the '!' be in a statement

Tags: symbols, patindex

I am reviewing scripts written by differenct coders and see many statement like:

```
((patindex('%,'+rtrim(ad.Dept)+',%', @vcP1Input) != 0) .
```

and I am wondering what the '!' is being used for.

Comment: [`!=` is the same as `<>`, not equal to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190296(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: `!` itself is no statement in this case.. It's `!=` and compares if the left and right are `not equel`, as stated above..

Answer (score 1):

`!` means **not** in this case.

So the `!=` means **not equal**.

Answer (score 1):

It means inequality.
Left side (patindex('%,'+rtrim(ad.Dept)+',%', @vcP1Input) is not equal to right side (0)

Answer (score 1):

`!=` is the negation of `==`

for example

```
if(obj == null)
{
   // do stuff1
}
else
{
   // do stuff2
}
```

is the same like

```
if(obj != null)
{
   // do stuff2
}
else
{
   // do stuff1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL, `!=` means [not equal to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190296(v=sql.90).aspx).

Your expression

```
((PATINDEX('%,' + RTRIM(ad.Dept)+',%', @vcP1Input) != 0)
```

is true if it can find the the trimmed value of `ad.Dept` in the string `@vcP1Input`, that is if [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395(v=sql.110).aspx) returns anything else than 0.